# Chain 3 queries into one to export the data to a csv

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

So I been battling with this for a little quite a bit today.  I have these three queries.

This gives me the percentage of valid emails.

```
SELECT (sum(case when c_email IS not NULL then 1 end )*100.00)/
        COUNT( c_number) as percentage, d_id, d_name
FROM distinct_customers group by d_id, d_name;
```

This counts the number of customers

```
select count(distinct c_number) from distinct_customers;
```

This counts the number of customers when email is null

```
select count(distinct c_number) from distinct_customers where and c_email is not null;
```

I am trying to chain these three queries and combine them into one so that I can generate a report in my application with that data in a csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the condition on your third query you could just add all the select values into one query. To work around that, you can use conditional aggregation. Note that since this is MySQL, you can take advantage of the fact that booleans are treated as 1 or 0 in a numeric context and do away with your `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT d_id, d_name,
       SUM(c_email IS NOT NULL) * 100.00 / COUNT(c_number) AS percentage,
       COUNT(DISTINCT c_number) AS total_customers,
       SUM(c_email IS NULL) AS null_emails
FROM distinct_customers
WHERE d_id='A00007' 
GROUP BY d_id, d_name;
```

To get data for all `d_id` values, simply remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Hi nick, this is almost there, only problem is that "Total_customers" and null emails are the same value. example

`A00007 A00007 Ibex Dealer 9.259259 54 54
`

Comment: @jesus2kus sorry - I copied the `COUNT` from your query and forgot to change it to `SUM` for the null emails. See my edit.

Comment: Thats it. Thank you Nick

Comment: Indeed. Still, you can always ask another question if need be...

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
select sum(case when coalesce(c_email, '') != '' and d_id='A00007' then 1 end )*100.00/
        count(c_number) else 0 end as percentage
        , sum(case when d_id='A00007' then 1 else 0 end) as count_1
        , sum(case when d_id='A00007' and coalesce(c_email, '') !='' then 1 else 0 end) as count_2
        , d_id, d_name
from distinct_customers
group by d_id, d_name;
```

If you just want to merge the results. use `union all`.

```
select sum(case when coalesce(c_email, '') != '' and d_id='A00007' then 1 end )*100.00/
            count(c_number) else 0 end as percentage           
            , d_id, d_name
    from distinct_customers
    group by d_id, d_name
union all
select sum(case when d_id='A00007' then 1 else 0 end) as count_1          
            , d_id, d_name
    from distinct_customers
    group by d_id, d_name
union all
select sum(case when d_id='A00007' and coalesce(c_email, '') !='' then 1 else 0 end) as count_2
            , d_id, d_name
    from distinct_customers
    group by d_id, d_name;
```

Comment: Thank you, how would the query look like without a where clause? (all)

Comment: @jesus2kus, it wont, because it will fall to `else 0`

Comment: ah, I edited my original question to be all.  can I chain those three queries into one?

Comment: @jesus2kus, you mean merge the results?

Comment: yes, without the where clause. (sorry for the confusion)